# The DOM/scripting bridge is disabled error in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, silverlight-5.0

I Have been trying to build a custom Silverlight application in Visual Studio 2013. I am trying to pass custom Parameters in the application. I have referred this link for creating such an application.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189004%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

When I try to debug the application I get this error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The DOM/scripting bridge is disabled.
at System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.VerifyThreadAndEnabled()
at System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.get_Document()
at testplayer.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(UInt32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
```

CAn anyone please let me know.

Thanks